# How to build a textarea with character counter and max length in EXT.JS?

Tags: javascript, extjs

I am creating this window in an Ext.js application. How to I implement the text under the text area which count downs as the user types and won't let him/her type once the max length is reached?

Comment: Set `maxLength` and `enforceMaxLength` properties for the text area, add a `label` field for the counter, listen to text area's `change` event and update the counter label based on text area's `getValue().length`. Which part do you have troubles with?

Answer (score 3):

With Extjs 5/6 you can do this using the viewModel, like:

```
Ext.widget('container', {

        viewModel: {
            data: {
                value: ''
            },
            formulas: {
                count: {
                    bind: '{value}',
                    get: function(value){
                        return 140 - value.length;
                    }
                }
            }
        },

        items: [{
            xtype: 'textareafield',
            enforceMaxLength: true,
            maxLength: 140,
            bind: '{value}'
        }, {
            xtype: 'box',
            bind: '{count}'
        }]
    })
```

Working Example: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1eht

Comment: You, Sir are awesome. Thank you. It works perfectly.